# How to solve Python Web Scraping Error 10053

Tags: python, web-scraping, resque-retry

I'm having a Certain Problem in Python Web Scraping . The background is that I want to scrape all  Food recipes on http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/ ! Now, Below is My Code

```
def extract_all_information():
file_name='links_all_recipes.txt'
links=read_all_links(file_name)
count=1
counter=0
for link in links:
    Recipes=open('All_Recipes.txt','a',encoding='utf-8')
    url='http://'+link
    single_recipe=recipe.collect_all_information(url)
    Recipes.write(str(single_recipe))
    Recipes.write('\n')
    counter+=1
    if counter>20:
        counter=0
        time.sleep(2)
    count+=1
    Recipes.close()
```

The Code to extract the information (like Author) on a Single recipes is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
def extract_author(recipe_url):
recipe=requests.get(recipe_url)
rsoup = BeautifulSoup(recipe.text, "lxml")
result = ''
for tag in rsoup.find_all(itemprop='author'):
    result = tag.contents[0]
return result
```

You can assume that all the other Function (like Extract_cooking_time() and extract_preparation_time ()and so on are similar to the above function) And Eventually, I call all of these functions (which extract a specific information related to a recipe) in collect_all_information () to extract everything related to a single recipe and i call this Function collect_all_information in the loop for every Url ! And Each time, I extract all the information related to a specific recipe, I append this information to a file called Recipes.txt

Now, the issue that I'm having is , the Error below

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))

This Error comes after I download approximately 1000 recipes (there are total of 11,000 some recipes and i want to scrape/download all of them, i have the links to all the recipes, and on each recipe, i extract some information like cooking time, preparation time, author, ingredients and so on) , I've looked for similar answers to this but each answer says that this error can be due to different reasons. Here's my intuition , i think this error is somehow related to max number of data scraped in a unit time (means limit exceeded), and i think i should fix that (I already tried to do that with a time sleep of 2 seconds after scraping 20 recipes each, but still receiving this error) !

Just some more information, I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 and Python 3, Windows 10 ! Can someone be so kind to tell me the reason I'm having this error, and what should i modify in my code to solve it. Your solution can be anything as long as it is easy to understand and implement, Please also note that I tried to use the Package 'retry' but I'm unable to figure how should i use that, and where should i use that in my code ! So, you can also include that in your answer !

Just to be clear, I'm maintaining the variable 'count' to tell me where the problem occurs, I print it before appending a recipe to the text file, (after how, many iterations does this problem occur) ! And I append in the file so that even though there comes a problem like this, at least I have download some recipes and saved them in my hardware –

Thanks a Lot for your time in advance

Comment: BTW: you can edit question and add text in question, not in comment.

Comment: you have problem with connection so where is code in which you connect to server ? You show code which is useless in your problem. And always show full error message (Traceback) there can be other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: Please See the Code Now, As for the trace back, I'm really sorry but i accidentally closed the output and now i would have to run it again and wait for almost an hour to get this error so...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def extract_author(recipe_url):
    recipe = requests.get(recipe_url, headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"})
    rsoup = BeautifulSoup(recipe.text, "lxml")
    meta =  rsoup.find("div",{"class":"recipe-leading-info"})
    desc = meta.find("p", {"itemprop":"description"})
    author = meta.find("a",{"itemprop":"author"})
    ingredients = [(list(x.strings)[0], list(x.strings)[1]) for x in rsoup.findAll("li", {"itemprop":"ingredients"})]


    infodct = dict(Author=author, Description=desc, Ingredients=ingredients)
    print(infodct)

extract_author(recipe_url=link)
```

I looks like you forgot to specify the "a" tag. I used this url to test: "http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/bananabread_85720"

You don't need to findAll unless you are expecting multiple tags to be returned like if it was a list of authors. It also might cut down on some of your processing time as would having all your extract functions in one. Otherwise you ae telling the parser to make a request for every peice of info. Just make one request and pull everything. Also, it is usually good practice to set the user-agent header. I usually encounter this as the most common cause of request errors.